# Can I sacrifice the same permanent for two different sacrifice costs?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-stack

Hi im new the mtg and have a question about the deck im playing.

so I use "Ravenous Intruders" ability (sacrifice an artifact gain +2/+2 until the end of the turn)

the artifact I sacrifice is "Implement of Combustion"

"Implement of Combustion" has an ability where I can pay 1 red mana and sacrifice it to deal 1 damage

would I be able to activate "Implement of Combustion" ability on top of Ravenous Intruder's ability so I can buff him and deal the 1 damage or would sacrificing implement leave no target for ravenous intruder so he does not buff?

Comment: While your question is a duplicate, it's interesting that you mention the Implement. Implements are designed so that the second ability (draw a card) happens when the implement goes to the graveyard. This means the card draw portion happens whether you use the first ability or use something else (like Ravenous Intruders) to sacrifice it.